# Why is there a difference between using c++ string+string temporary object by different compilers?

Tags: c++, string, temporary-objects

Please look at this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string hello = "Hello"
         , world = "World";

    const char *p = (hello+world).c_str();
    cout << "STRING: " << p <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have no reputation, can't post images so that I will write results by hand.

= Visual Studio 2013 ver.12.0.30110.00

```
STRING:
```

= Dev-C++ ver.4.9.9.2

```
STRING: HelloWorld
```

The first following is execution result that compiled by Visual Studio.

Second is compiled by Dev-C++.

**I wonder what makes this difference.**

I will be looking forward to your reply. Thanks :)

Comment: It is *undefined behaviour*. That is a reason you can observe a difference.

Comment: Thanks @juanchopanza,
I think it is important that avoid using undefined behavior...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(hello+world).c_str()` is only valid until the trailing `;`. Accessing the memory afterwards is undefined behavior.

Visual studio probably actually clears the memory, Dev-C++ doesn't bother. Try building a release version with Visual studio (optimizations on) and you'll probably see the same behavior.

Comment: It could also depend on how the `<<` operator uses memory.  If `std::string` uses SSO, it will also depend on whether the temporary string is small enough to fit; if so, `p` will point to an on stack location, which will be overwritten when `operator<<` is called.  And so on: you really can't make any general statement.

Comment: Thanks @Luchian Grigore
I think Visual Studio bother with optimizations :)